# Retrieve Records Less than 90 Days Old

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use the below code to bring back all records that are not older than 90 days from a table:

```
Set PlatinumList = db.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT FORMATTED_CTN FROM CTN_LIST " _
    & "WHERE ((Status='Available') AND (Category='Platinum')) " _
    & "AND (In_Offer_List = True) " _
    & "AND (DATEDIFF(day, Created_DT, current_date()< 90);", _
    dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
```

I keep getting a syntax error in query expression error when I try and run the code.

I think I'm formatting the date section of the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date token for day is `"d"` rather than `day` and your missing a closing `)`

```
.. AND (DATEDIFF("d", Created_DT, current_date()) < 90);"
```

(You also need current_date() as a vba func)